# How do I correctly apply regex so array does not have empty string at the start

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm struggling with a regex.

I am able to split the string at the required location, but when it is added to an array, the array has an empty string at the start.

```js
// This is the string I am wanting to split.
// I want the first 4 words to be separated from the remainder of the string
const chatMessage = "This is a string that I want to split";

// I am using this regex
const r = /(^(?:\S+\s+\n?){4})/;

const chatMessageArr = chatMessage.split(r);

console.log(chatMessageArr);
```

It returns:

```
[ '', 'This is a string ', 'that I want to split' ]
```

But need it to return:

```
[ 'This is a string ', 'that I want to split' ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? `.slice()`, a different regex, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use string split here, I would use a regex replacement:

```js
var chatMessage = "This is a string that I want to split";
var first = chatMessage.replace(/^\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}).*$/, "$1");
var last = chatMessage.replace(/^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}\s+(.*$)/, "$1");
console.log(chatMessage);
console.log(first);
console.log(last);
```

Comment: So would you suggest the below to place the now two separate strings into one array?
chatMessageArr.push(chatMessage.replace(/^\s*(\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}).*$/, "$1"));
chatMessageArr.push(chatMessage.replace(/^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){3}\s+(.*$)/, "$1"));

Comment: Yes, you could do that.  There might also be some canonical way to split a string in JavaScript on a single nth occurrence of some pattern.  This might be a better alternative to the answer I gave you above.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second capture group to the regexp and use `.match()` instead of `.split()`.

```js
// This is the string I am wanting to split.
// I want the first 4 words to be separated from the remainder of the string
const chatMessage = "This is a string that I want to split";

// I am using this regex
const r = /(^(?:\S+\s+\n?){4})(.*)/;

const chatMessageArr = chatMessage.match(r);
chatMessageArr.shift(); // remove the full match

console.log(chatMessageArr);
```